# Determine whether this is true: If $a_n \rightarrow +\infty$ then $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{n}^{n}}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine whether the following is true: If sequence $a_n \rightarrow +\infty$ then the infinite series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_{n}^{n}} $  converges.

**Note:** I am looking for feedback on whether my solution is correct or if I am at least on the right track.

**Attempt:**

A sequence $a_n \rightarrow +\infty$ means:

$$ \forall\ M\in \mathbb{R} \ \exists \ N\in \mathbb{N}\ \ s.t \ \forall\ n \geq N,\  a_n > M$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \forall\ M\in \mathbb{R} \ \exists \ N\in \mathbb{N}\ \ s.t \ \forall\ n \geq N,\ \frac{1}{M} > \frac{1}{a_n}$$

So let $\epsilon > 0$, This means we have:

$$\Bigg| \sum_{n = k+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_{n}^{n}} \Bigg| \leq  \sum_{n = k+1}^{\infty} \Bigg| \frac{1}{a_{n}^{n}} \Bigg| < \sum_{n = k+1}^{\infty} \Bigg| \frac{1}{M^{n}} \Bigg| < \sum_{n = k+1}^{\infty} \Bigg| \frac{1}{n^{p}} \Bigg| < \epsilon $$

It has been shown that $$\sum_{n = k+1}^{\infty} \Bigg| \frac{1}{n^{p}} \Bigg|$$ converges for $p > 1$ now since $n \in \mathbb{N},\ n > 1$ eventually. So the original series converges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are bringing in the $p$-test unnecessarily. Once you know that all the terms in the tail of the sequence satisfy $a_n > 2$, say when $n>N$, then you can compare
$$
\bigg|\sum_{n > N}\frac{1}{a_n^n}\bigg| \le \underbrace{\sum_{n> N}\frac{1}{2^n}}_{\text{geometric series}} = \frac{1}{2^N},
$$
hence the original series converges.

Comment: Is it the case that $a_n > 2$ will always be true solely because we are assuming $a_n \rightarrow +\infty$?

Comment: @dc3rd yes, past a certain point $N$, pick $M=2$ in the definition you quoted

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you got the idea right. But some remarks on your solution -

1. You switched between $a_n$ and $x_n$
2. the "iff" is not correct, because the second line is solved by any $x_n < 0$ as well
3. $M$ in the "iff" was quantified over; you should pick one before making the lines in the computation
4. $k$ appears suddenly; does it matter what $k$ is?
5. $p$ appears suddenly; perhaps you want it to relate to $k$?

Lets attempt to fix this, as if we forgot that the geometric series converged...

First lets choose some $M>1$. then $a_n >M$ when $n>k$ for some $k$. Then, note that
$M^k > k^p$
is the same as $p < \frac{k}{\log k}\log M$, so if necessary make $k$ bigger so that $p=2$ is allowed. Then for $n>k$, $M^n > n^p$
$$ \sum_{n=k+1}^K\frac1{M^k}\le\sum_{n=k+1}^K \frac1{n^2} < \pi^2/6$$
so the tail sum converges.

Comment: 3. if I am going to pick an M, what comes to my mind is that based on the Archimedian property of $\mathbb{R}$ there iwll exist an M s.t $\frac{1}{M} < \epsilon$ So choose M to be large enough to satisfy this?

4. & 5. to relate $p$ to $k$, perhaps the statement that for all $k > p$?

2. Should I state for M > 0, to remove that possibility?

Comment: Well $M$ doesn't actually have to be very large, you don't even need the tail sum to be small, just finite.

Comment: What about my assumptions for 4. & 5.?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there?

Comment: you mentioned I should try to relate $p$ to $k$.  So I though a way to relate them would be that my statement would be true if we allow only for $k > p$

Comment: @dc3rd all $k,p$ such that? You don't need something that complicated, you just need $k$ large so that $a_n>M=1$ say, then for $p>1$ small enough the inequality you are using holds. But you do not need the comparison to a $p$-series if this is too complicated, see the other answer

Comment: Thanks Calvin. I agree with the simplicity of the other answer, but I feel it would make sense to understand the complex intricacies of the p-series so I can apply it better further along the road.